# Message coming in console at application startup is "Controller required a bean of type 'com.arnab.repository.BookRepository' that couldn't be found."

Tags: spring-boot, maven, web-services, jpa, crud

While I'm trying to start up my Spring Boot CRUD application using JPA and postgresql database, I am getting this message on console

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field bookRepo in com.arnab.controller.BookController required a bean of type 'com.arnab.repository.BookRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.arnab.repository.BookRepository' in your configuration.
```

My Project Structure is
[image]

My Driver class is

```
package com.arnab.LibraryManagement;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.arnab.LibraryManagement","com.arnab.config","com.arnab.repository","com.arnab.controller","com.arnab.entity_Bean_DTO"})
public class LibraryManagementApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LibraryManagementApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My Repository interface is

```
package com.arnab.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.arnab.entity_Bean_DTO.Books;

@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Books, Long> 
{

}
```

My POJO (Entity) class is

```
package com.arnab.entity_Bean_DTO;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Books 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "bookid")
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name = "bookname")
    private String BookName;
    
    @Column(name = "genre")
    private String Genre;
    
    @Column(name = "author")
    private String Author;
    
    @Column(name = "availability_status")
    private String AvailabilityStatus;
    
    @Column(name = "price")
    private double price;
        
    public Books() {
        super();
    }

    public Books(long id, String bookName, String genre, String author, String availabilityStatus, double price) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        BookName = bookName;
        Genre = genre;
        Author = author;
        AvailabilityStatus = availabilityStatus;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBookName() {
        return BookName;
    }

    public void setBookName(String bookName) {
        BookName = bookName;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return Genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(String genre) {
        Genre = genre;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return Author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        Author = author;
    }

    public String getAvailabilityStatus() {
        return AvailabilityStatus;
    }

    public void setAvailabilityStatus(String availabilityStatus) {
        AvailabilityStatus = availabilityStatus;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

My Controller class is

```
package com.arnab.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.arnab.entity_Bean_DTO.Books;
import com.arnab.repository.BookRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/library")
public class BookController 
{   
    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepo;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/allBooks")
    public List<Books> findAllBook()
    {
        System.out.println("All books are = "+bookRepo.findAll());
        return bookRepo.findAll();
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "/addBooks")
    public ResponseEntity<Books> addBooks(@RequestBody Books book)
    {
        Books saveBooks = bookRepo.save(book);
        System.out.println("Save books is = "+saveBooks);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(saveBooks,HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

My appication.properties file is

```
#DATABASE PROPERTIES

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/library?currentSchema=library-management
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root

# JPA PROPERTIES
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

My POM.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.15-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.arnab</groupId>
    <artifactId>Library-Management</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Library-Management</name>
    <description>Library mnagement project for springboot </description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

I have tried many solutions but nothing's seem to be working. How to fix this?

Comment: Move your `LibraryManagementApplication` to the `com.arnab` package and remove the `@ComponentScan` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options. Here what you need to do.

1. Add below annotations in your main class as well. As the repository package is different,we need to explicitly define the JPA repositories.

   @EnableJpaRepositories({"com.arnab.repository"})
   @EntityScan("com.arnab.entity_Bean_DTO")
2. Move your main class to the base package like below and update your component scan annotation to com.arnab.*

[image]